# Code Coverage for Apex Controller and VF Component

Tags: code-coverage

I am trying to cover code for my VF Page controller and its VF Component but I am not able to cover. I am at 61% & 64% now. Not able to cover code which is try block of VFPController and create contact lines in Try block of cmpController. Need help to cover 90% of my both controllers

**VF Controller**

```
public class VFPController {
    public String custLastName { get; set; }
    public String custFirstName { get; set; }
    public String custAddr1 { get; set; }
    public String custPC { get; set; }
    public String custPhone { get; set; }
    public String custEmailId { get; set; }
    
    public Boolean ShowSrchBlock { get; set; }
    public List<Customers> lstCustSrch { get; set; }
    public List<Customers> lstCustSrchFormatted { get; set; }
    
    public VFPController(){

    }

    public PageReference customerSearch() {
        lstCustSrch = new List<Customers>();
        qryCustomerData();
        return null;
    }
    
    public void qryCustomerData(){
        ShowSrchBlock = false;
        //Ln_Cd from User Object
        Id userId = userinfo.getUserId();
        User Usr = [SELECT Id, Name, Ln_Cd, Profile.Name, UserRole.Name FROM User where Id=:userId LIMIT 1];

        lstCustSrch.clear();
        if (verifyInputData()) {
            try {
                APIResponses.CustomerSrchResp custSrch = APIController.srchCustomers(Usr.Ln_Cd,custLastName,custFirstName,custPhone,custAddr1,custPC,custEmailId);
                lstCustSrch = custSrch.customers;

                lstCustSrchFormatted = new List<Customers>();
                for (Customers customer : lstCustSrch) {
                    customer.customerName = customer.customerName.trim();
                    customer.address1 = customer.address1.trim();
                    customer.cityName = customer.cityName.trim();
                    customer.stateCode = customer.stateCode.trim();
                    customer.postalCode = customer.postalCode.trim();
                    customer.mobilePhoneNumber = customer.mobilePhoneNumber.trim();
                    
                    lstCustSrchFormatted.add(customer);
                    ShowSrchBlock = true;
                } 
            } catch (APIController.InfoException ex) {
                Apexpages.addmessage(new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info, ex.getmessage()));
                clearFields();
            } catch (APIController.ErrorException ex) {
                Apexpages.addmessage(new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, ex.getmessage()));                
                clearFields();
            } catch (APIController.SystemException ex) {
                Apexpages.addmessage(new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, ex.getmessage()));
                clearFields();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean verifyInputData(){
        if(!String.isBlank(custFirstName) && String.isBlank(custLastName)){
            Apexpages.addmessage(new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Please enter Customer Last Name'));
            return false;
        } else if(String.isBlank(custLastName) && String.isBlank(custPhone) && String.isBlank(custEmailId)){
            Apexpages.addmessage(new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info, 'Please enter one of the following... Last Name, Phone Number, Email Id'));
            return false;
        } else {
           return true;
        }
    }
    
    public void clearFields() {
        custLastName = '';
        custFirstName = '';
        custAddr1 = '';
        custPC = '';
        custPhone = '';
        custEmailId = '';
        
        ShowSrchBlock = false;
    }
}
```

**VF Component Controller**

```
public class cmpController {
    public Customers getCustomer { get; set; }
    public String qryUnqNo { get; set; }
    Account acc;
    Contact con;
    Id conId;

    public cmpController() {
        getCustomer = new Customers();
    }

    public pageReference showContactData() {    
        qryUnqNo = getCustomer.customerUnqNo;

        //Code for verify if contact exist? If not create account and contact record and display contact record
        List<Contact> listContact = [SELECT Id, LastName, Unq_No__c FROM Contact 
                                     WHERE Unq_No__c =:qryUnqNo LIMIT 1];
        
        if(listContact.isEmpty()) {
            //create contact and account record for customer
            try {
                Account acct = new Account();
                acct.name = getCustomer.customerName;
                insert acct;

                ID acctID = acct.ID;
            
                // Add a contact to this account
                Contact con = new Contact();
                con.AccountId = acctID;
                con.LastName = getCustomer.customerName;
                con.Unq_No__c = qryUnqNo;
                insert con;

                conId = con.Id;
            } catch(DmlException e) {
                System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
            }        
        } else {
            for(Contact con : listContact){
                conId = con.Id;
            }
        }
        return redirectToContactPage(conId);
    }
    
    public PageReference redirectToContactPage(Id contactId) { 
        PageReference conPage = new PageReference('/lightning/r/Contact/' + contactId + '/view');
        return conPage;
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class TestClasses{
    static testmethod void testVFPController(){
        String Ln_Cd;
        String custLastName;
        String custFirstName;
        String custAddr1;
        String custPC;
        String custPhone;
        String custEmailId;
        Boolean ShowSrchBlock = false;
        
        List<Customers> lstCustomerSearch = new List<Customers>();
        List<Customers> lstCustomerSearchFormatted = new List<Customers>();
                
        PageReference pageRef = Page.VFPCustomerSrch;
        VFPController testController = new VFPController();

        Test.StartTest();

        pageRef.getParameters().put('Ln_Cd', 'Abc1');
        pageRef.getParameters().put('custLastName', 'Customer,Test1');
        //pageRef.getParameters().put('custPhone', '1234567890');
        //pageRef.getParameters().put('custEmailId', 'abc@test.com');
        
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        String bodyStr='{"customers":[{"address1":"Addr1           ","birthDate":"1970-01-01","cityName":"City                 ","customerUnqNo":"C44444","customerName":"Customer,Test1            ","mobilePhoneNo":"1234567890         ","postalCode":"12345     ","customerAccNo":"11119999   ","stateCode":"TS"}]}';
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new APIMockHttpResponse(200,'Complete',bodyStr,null));
        
        APIResponses.CustomerSrchResp cSrch = APIController.srchCustomers(Ln_Cd,custLastName,custFirstName,custPhone,custAddr1,custPC,custEmailId);
        //APIResponses.CustomerSrchResp cSrch = APIController.srchCustomers('Abc1','Customer','','','','','');
        
        
        testController.customerSearch();
        testController.getLevelOptions();
        testController.clearFields();
        
        Test.StopTest();
    }

    static testmethod void testCmpController(){
        Customers getCustomerTest = new Customers();
    
        cmpController testCompController = new cmpController();
        
        Test.StartTest();
        
        String bodyStr='{"customers":[{"address1":"Addr1           ","birthDate":"1970-01-01","cityName":"City                 ","customerUnqNo":"C44444","customerName":"Customer,Test2            ","mobilePhoneNo":"1234567890         ","postalCode":"12345     ","customerAccNo":"11119999   ","stateCode":"TS"}]}';
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new APIMockHttpResponse(200,'Complete',bodyStr,null));

        APIResponses.CustomerSrchResp cSrch = APIController.srchCustomers(Ln_Cd,custLastName,custFirstName,custPhone,custAddr1,custPC,custEmailId);
        //APIResponses.CustomerSrchResp cSrch = APIController.srchCustomers('Abc1','Customer','','','','','');

        getCustomerTest = cSrch.customers[0];
        
        testCompController.showContactData();
        
        Test.StopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. It helped me understand possible scenarios code will not be covered but I need to cover code at least 75% but I am at 64% so need help how to cover for loop in first class and if condition in 2nd class/component

Comment: The problem with your question is that we can't tell what lines are covered, what isn't, which means we'd have to create all your custom fields, make some educated guesses, and just generally spend a lot more time than is feasible for these types of questions. Exceptions are usually difficult to cover, so you should minimize the amount of lines of code you spend handling them. You might go with Dependency Injection, you might need to make your callout mock throw an exception, and/or other tricks.